# CSS Refactoring with tag id

Tags: html, css

I do not have a firm grasp on CSS Selectors. 
I know the below CSS is sparse but it will get me going.

I want a table's borders to be the same for th and td.

```
#eventRegistrationNotificationEmail th{
  width:25%;
  border: 1px  solid #999999;
}

#eventRegistrationNotificationEmail td{
  width:75%;
  border: 1px  solid #999999;
}
```

I know I can do something like the below but how do I do it with an ID or Class?

```
td, th{
  border: 1px  solid #999999;
}
```

Comment: Go read [**this**](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-CSS2/selector.html%23adjacent-selectors).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it exactly the same way, just separate your selectors with a comma and the style is applied to all of them.

```
#eventRegistrationNotificationEmail td, 
#eventRegistrationNotificationEmail th {
    border: 1px  solid #999999;
}
```

You could also use a CSS pre-processor like [LESS](http://lesscss.org/) which lets you next styles in the `.less` file which are combined together when the processor is run:

```
#eventRegistrationNotificationEmail {
    td, th {
        border: 1px solid #999999;
    }
}
```

Comment: now I see what was tripping me up. I see you have to fully qualify each tag.  I think the .less thing is a bit advanced for me right now but I will remember to look into it.

Answer (score 1):

I realised that name 'eventRegistrationNotificationEmail' is your table id:

```
 table#eventRegistrationNotificationEmail th, table#eventRegistrationNotificationEmail td{
    border: 1px  solid #999999;
    }
```